# git repository not recognized during rails deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an error from my remote git repository when I try to deploy my rails app. It's telling me that it's not a git repository, yet I can push and pull from it without issue. However I recently had issues with git not being found by bash, but it was simply a path variable issue that cropped up when I installed macports (I think). It's now fixed. Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide!
The error output is below:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:project myUser$ cap deploy:update
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git master"
fatal: 'git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/releases/20120403193900; true"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/releases/20120403193900; true'
    command finished in 639ms
Command git ls-remote git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git master returned status code pid 1815 exit 128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the repository address WAS malformed as the user above suggested. However, the problem was resolved by adding an 'ssh:' prefix to the repository address. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you've got a malformed Git URL:

```
git ls-remote git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git master
```

Should be:

```
git ls-remote git@server.example.ca:/usr/local/git_root/project.git master
```

They follow SCP protocol (see the [git-clone](http://jk.gs/git-clone.html) manpage for more).

Answer (score 3):

Your key must be available to ssh-agent

I had same problem. Solved with "ssh-add yourkey" , where yourkey is the path do id_rsa, and you can check with: ssh-add -L, if ok will return your public key

Answer (score -3):

Could you try deleting the local repository and re-cloning it?

Comment: This should not be necessary.

Comment: this can lead to unpredictable consequences.